# PHP Curl script to pull data from remote server every 10 minutes

Tags: php, xml, database, curl, remote-server

I'm trying to create a PHP script which pulls xml data (text and images) from a remote server and inserts it in a local database. I need to run this script every 10 minutes or so (and overwrite the existing data in my db)... if I don't get a response from the server after about a minute, I would like the request to abort until the next time the script runs 10 minutes later. Can anyone please either give me some idea as to how I can achieve this or point me to a tutorial that explains it in fairly simple terms?

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm looking for help with the PHP script itself, not sure that was clear in my initial post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a run of the mill curl script that connects to a remote server and fetches data, inserts into your db, set limits and exceptions. Then create an entry in crontab to run this script every 10 minutes. I have a similar setup running for one of my website which fetches data from stock exchange and updates a local cache, another script has the task of consuming the cache as and when required.

Comment: OK thanks, do you know where I could find a similar PHP script I could base mine on?

Comment: A very basic curl script http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php and a link to crontab entry generator http://www.clockwatchers.com/cron_tool.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about cron jobs? They're used to schedule periodic tasks like executing scripts from the server.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good primer on how Cron Jobs work: http://www.webmasters-central.com/article-blog/tutorials/cron-tutorial-managing-cron-tab-or-cron-job-is-easy/

Comment: Thanks, I do know how to set up the cron job, it's actually the PHP script which I'm wrestling with...