# Running scripts in server background-process?

Tags: php, linux, background-process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Curl script to pull data from remote server every 10 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051038/php-curl-script-to-pull-data-from-remote-server-every-10-minutes)

My friend's website has XML generator for news feeds. I'm reading data from there and use it on my website (I have permission to do that). But... I have a script for that job under my admin panel so I have to call it manually and wait until processing is done (can't close my browser). It works great but problem is that I need to update my database every 30 minutes (or every hour) and I can't stay in front of my computer doing that 24 hours daily.

I'm now wondering, is there something that I can do to make this process automatized on server-side? In short, I want to run some kind of scheduler on my server that runs my script every (lets say) 30 minutes and do that job without my physical presence in front of computer.

I have not experience at all about this and actually don't know where to look to find solution for this problem. Don't know is that even possible?

So what I need here as answer is some suggestions or links or whatever helps in order to find solution for my problem. It's not urgent and I have a lot of time to learn. Just tell me where to start searching.

Sorry if this is duplicate question, but I couldn't search for anything because I didn't know what search terms to use and have not idea yet what I have to look for.

I really appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: no, but I'm going to that. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is [**cron**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) *(quoting)* :

> Cron is a time-based job scheduler in Unix-like computer operating
>   systems.
> Cron enables users to schedule jobs *(commands or shell
>   scripts)* to run periodically at certain times or dates. 
> It is
>   commonly used to automate system maintenance or administration...

Comment: thanks mate, I'm going to do little research about cron, but according to this description, it sounds like what I need. I've heard earlier about cron but never got into it.

Comment: May I control cron jobs from PHP. Want to integrate that in admin panel to start/stop change scheduling time, etc. Just wonder before I start learning and practicing its usage.

Comment: If you want to "control" those jobs from PHP, a solution could be to have your PHP panel administer something like a database *(in which you'll store which jobs are active, when they should run, ...)*, and a cronjob that runs every minute, running jobs as indicated by the database.

Comment: later, reading about cron, I found out how cron works (so that "control" question was really stupid by me). If I understood what you said, you suggest creating something like jobs table with on/off/start-time/end-time flags and check it out every minute using cron if any condition match with server time. If so, that might work. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's kind of what I suggested :-) ;; one thing you might have to think about is to make sure one job does not run twice at the same time *(if it's already running and not finished, maybe you don't want it re-started by the cronjob)*

Comment: yes, I was thinking about that, but best I can do is to set in-progress state flag somewhere in database and remove it after job has been finished, and check for it when cron fires my script. Because I'm still not experienced with cron enough, that may work well. Thanks anyway.

Comment: About the "in-progress" flag in the database *(which is not a bad idea)*, don't forget that your script might sometimes just crash *(like Fatal Error)*, and not un-set the flag

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`curl`](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_curl.htm) in order to do the job you are doing right now in your browser, and after that, put that command in [`cron`](http://www.scrounge.org/linux/cron.html)